# Tablecellcollection is not callable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ironpython

This is a dumb question, but I just cant find an answer. I want to do something as simple as this in IronPython, something I did in asp.net vb.net to capture the id of a table displayed in a gridview or datagrid

```
iid = e.Item.Cells(2).Text
```

But I get "Tablecellcollection is not callable". Any idea or alternative to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use brackets around the indexing portion of your expression instead of of parentheses.

```
iid = e.Item.Cells[2].Text
```